# Trigger Email Send Notification from a smart capture submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, lookup, triggered-send, smart-capture

I have a landing page built in cloud page in SMFC with the smart capture form. The form is submitting the data to a DE table just fine.

Currently right now I am exporting this data manually to sftp and sending it to the Sales team on a daily basis.

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this where if a new contact is added to a DE and somehow fire a trigger email send to the Sales showing the details of the submission by email with some look up ampscript.

It is something I saw Woo Foo form do and was wondering if that is possible in SFMC.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your sales team is using a distribution group so that a single email address is used to email the group, you can use Journey Builder to send an email for each record added through your form.

When creating the Data Extension for the form, you will want to have the field for EmailAddress configured to be populated with the email address for your Sales team. Make the EmailAddress field a hidden field and enter the email address for your Sales team.

If you are collecting a subscriber's email address, you will want to use a Text data type for the field so that it does not cause issues with the emails sent to the Sales Team and be sure that you are associating the field for the Sales Team to SubscriberKey so that the contact flowing through the journey is the contact associated to the Sales Team email address. This will also make sure you aren't overwriting any existing subscribers email addresses with the Sales Team's email address.

When setting up your journey be sure to update the settings to allow re-entry at any time in case you have multiple subscribers fill out the form at the same time.

Comment: HI Travis, That is very helpful and I will try experimenting with it. I just have a question on the journey part or automation part like how do I trigger the journey to run when a new contact is added? So far on trigger part I just know in automation studio is when a file is dropped in the SFTP that will trigger the automation to run so am wondering if there is a possibility to do this when a data extension gets populated?

Comment: @Tfresh 
Here is the documentation for using Cloud Pages in Journey Builder:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_use_a_smart_capture_form_as_a_journey_builder_entry_event.htm&type=5

Comment: @Tfresh When you configure the entry for the Journey using a Cloud Pages entry event, the injection into the journey should occur within a few minutes of the form being submitted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the the info. I managed to set it up and its working great!

Answer (score -1):

Can you please let me know how you were able to trigger an email whenever a record is inserted in the DE? I am also trying to achieve the same but not able to find out how to trigger an email whenever a DE is populated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/189037)