# Can i send email to the subscriber and same email to 3rd person at same time using journey bulider on submit of smart capture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpage, smart-capture

I have a cloud page in SMFC with the smart capture form. The form is submitting the data to DE working fine.

I have created a journey to send a email, when user fill the smart capture form in my cloud page, Right now the email goes to the person who have filled the form.

I want to sent email to 3rd person as well to the subscriber who just filled the form.

So any one can let me know what changes i need to do for this.

Or

Is there any way i can do this.

I more thing i don't want to use two journeys for this until i don't have other solution.

Comment: Who is this other person you want to send an email to? Is it always the same email / subscriberkey?

Comment: Other Person mean to say any 3rd person, you can consider myFriend for now as a other person.

Comment: Okay. Is the email address and subscriber key going to remain the same always?

Comment: Updated the question, I am trying to implement this by this way [ https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270150/trigger-email-send-notification-from-a-smart-capture-submission ] But its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to accomplish this and your choice is largely going to depend on how comfortable you are with scripts/SQL. If the email address is static, then just add it as a CC on the email activity inside of your journey.

If the email address is dynamic, then it would probably be easiest to just run an hourly query on your data extension to pull out new entrants and deploy the email to your desired addresses. If this solution needs to be both dynamic and real-time, then you need to scrap the smart capture form and implement your own so that you can deploy a triggered send to the other address from a cloudpage on form submit.

If the solution needs to be dynamic, real-time *and recurring at dynamic ranges within your journey* then you'll need a custom JB activity.